# Python sort dictionary by a list of key values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of values that is the sort order:

```
order = ['foo', 'bar']
data = [{'name': 'bar', 'someData': 'someValue'}, {'name': 'foo', 'someData': 'someValue'}]
```

I would like to sort data (by 'name') based on order

Comment: Why would anyone give this -1 ? Im new to Python and i looked around for this sort here on stackoverflow and did not find a way to do this sort

Comment: This is a combination of [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/72899) and [How to sort a list according to another list?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12814667).

Comment: You can get downvoted for not providing enough information, not having a clear question, not showing what you have tried so far etc This link may help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can see that, but i dont know python well enough to combine them.

Answer (score 2):

you can go like this:

```
sorted(data, key = lambda x: order.index(x["name"]))
```

Comment: Getting: ValueError: substring not found, data dose contain 'name' but order dose not

Comment: You can only sort by order, if order actually contains all the names.

Comment: You would have to decide what ordering a key not in "order" list should get.

Comment: Thats a problem as names are dynamic

Comment: then you don't have a order list to sort by?

Comment: Yes i do, my mistake. The order list dose contain all names and the data list contains all the name fields, not sure why im getting this error

Comment: index throws ValueError when it doesnt find the string, so I am going to go out on a limb here and ask you to check again.

Comment: hmm, how to i lowerCase both ? sorted(fieldList, key=lambda x: fieldsOnly.index(x["name"].lower()))

Comment: better to lowercase order in advance

Comment: I know, but thats not posible as the sorted list names are case sensitive and need to remain that

Comment: performance will be shit but:
sorted(data, key = lambda x: list(map(str.lower,order)).index(x["name"].lower()))

Answer (score 1):

I would create an order mapping in advance to make the key function faster:

```
def create_key(order, field='name'):
    order_map={v: i for (i, v) in enumerate(order)} 
    def key(elem):
       return order_map[elem[field]]
    return key

data.sort(key=create_key(order))
```

Comment: Getting:  return order map[elem[field]] KeyError: 'name'

Comment: @Mythar apparently, not all the elements have that field.